# Set global Datetime offset for Azure website

Tags: datetime, azure, timezone, timezone-offset

I have an Azure website that have datetime set to GMT + 0. All of my users are located in GMT +2.

Is there a simple way how to set the time offset globaly on application startup so all the DateTime values will be rendered with the correct offset?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your programming language provides.  For example, in PHP, you can use `date_default_timezone_set`.  However, in .NET and many other languages, there is no way to change the default time zone - it will always use the local time zone of the machine it's running on.

It's good that Azure sets it's time zones to UTC.  It's really not good for a server application or web site to depend on the time zone settings of the computer it's running on.  You should simply rely on the features of the language to write your application such that you are in control of the time zone functionality.  For example, in .Net, you can use `TimeZoneInfo` to convert times to any time zone you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [DateTime.ToLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx)?